# Animation for charts in Keynote

Tags: keynote, animation

Does anyone know how to do the shrinking of chart animation in WWDC for the speed of swift?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the video where this is demonstrated?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w87fOAG8fjk at 1:45:00

Answer (score 2):

Keynote '09 supports chart builds, where individual segments/series of a chart can be separated in a build and animated individually. You can select the chart builds along with the other builds in the Build selector.

You can find more information about creating a chart build in Keynote '09 in the Apple KB article:

- [Keynote '09: Creating a Chart Build](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH6145)